# Bounding a double sequence

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits

> Suppose that $a_{n,m}$ are non-negative real numbers such that
>   $$
> \sum_{n\ge1}a_{n,m}<\infty
> $$
>   for each $m\ge1$ and
>   $$
> \lim_{m\to\infty}\sum_{n\ge1}a_{n,m}
> $$
>   exists. Does that imply that there exist real numbers $b_n$ such that $a_{n,m}\le b_n$ and $\sum_{n\ge1} b_n<\infty$?

I am not sure if the answer is positive or negative. There are examples when we can find real numbers $b_n$: if $a_{n,m}$ does not depend on $m$ (i.e. $a_{n,m}=a_n$), we can choose $b_n=a_n$; if $a_{n,m}=c^{nm}$ with some $0<c<1$, then $c^{nm}\le c^{n}=b_n$.  However, I cannot find a counterexample.

Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Counterexample:**

Let $a_{n,m}=\frac{1}{m}\frac{(-1)^{n}}{n}$

Then $\sum_{n\ge1}a_{n,m}<\infty$ and 
$\lim_{m\to\infty}\sum_{n\ge1}a_{n,m}=\lim_{m\to\infty} \frac{\ln 2}{m}=0$.

If there exists $(b_n)$ such that $a_{n,m}\le b_n$ then we have:
$a_{2n,1}=\frac{1}{2n} \le b_{2n}$ so $\sum b_{2n}$ diverges to $+\infty$.

Besides, we have $a_{2n+1,m} \le b_{2n+1}$ i.e $b_{2n+1}+\frac{1}{m(2n+1)}\ge0$ for all $m$. This implies $b_{2n+1} \ge 0$.

Hence $\sum b_{2n+1}$ either converges or goes to $+\infty$.

In both cases, $\sum b_{n}=\sum b_{2n}+\sum b_{2n+1}$ diverges.

Hence such a sequence does not exist.

**Edit: counterexample if $a_{n,m}>0$:**

Let $a_{n,m}$ defined by:
$a_{n,m}=\frac{1}{m}$ if $m\ge n$
$a_{n,m}=0$ otherwise.

Then for all $m$, $\sum_{n\ge1}a_{n,m}=1<\infty$.

But the sequence $(b_n)$ cannot exist as if that was the case, we would have $b_n \ge \frac{1}{n}$ for all $n$ so $\sum b_n$ would diverge.

Comment: I am sorry I forgot to mention that $a_{n,m}$ has to be non-negative. Could you come up with a counterexample when $a_{n,m}$ are non-negative? Thanks anyway.

Comment: @Cm7F7Bb see my edit.

Answer (score 1):

Let

$$a_{n,m}=\begin{cases}
2^{-m},&\text{if }n=1\\
2^{-1},&\text{if }n=m\\
2^{-n},&\text{otherwise}\;.
\end{cases}$$

Then

$$\sum_{n\ge 1}a_{n,m}=\sum_{n\ge 1}2^{-n}=1$$

for each $m\in\Bbb Z^+$, so

$$\lim_{m\to\infty}\sum_{n\ge 1}a_{n,m}=1\;.$$

For each $n\in\Bbb Z^+$ we have $\max_{m\in\Bbb Z^+}a_{n,m}=\frac12$, so the bounds $b_n$ have to be at least $\frac12$, and therefore $\sum_{n\ge 1}b_n=\infty$.

Comment: Thank you for the answer (+1)! Should it not be $\max_{{\color{red}m}\in\mathbb Z^+}a_{n,m}$ ($m$ instead of $n$)?

Comment: @Cm7F7Bb: It should indeed; thanks for catching that.

Answer (score 1):

Counterexample: Let $a_{n,m} = 1$ if $n=m,$ $a_{n,m} = 0$ otherwise. The hypotheses are then satisfied. If $a_{n,m}\le b_n$ for all $n,m,$ then $1 = a_{n,n}\le b_n$ for all $n.$ Thus $\sum b_n \ge 1 + 1 + \cdots = \infty.$